# M2Crypto: Converting der to pem

Tags: m2crypto

I am trying to convert `der` to `pem` using openssl M2Crypto library.
I am getting following exception for

```
p7 = SMIME.load_pkcs7_bio(raw_data)
```

Exception:

> M2Crypto.SMIME.PKCS7_Error: 140605685806848:error:0D078089:asn1
>   encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:missing
>   eoc:tasn_dec.c:493:Type=PKCS7 140605685806848:error:0906700D:PEM
>   routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1 lib:pem_oth.c:83: